# Counting different elements in an array

Tags: c++

I got this really easy project however i got stuck in a simple issue.

User enters a number not that is larger than 99 and smaller than 1 000 000.

I am supposed to get the number of digits in that number and how many times each one occurs

E.g: 112233 = 6 digits and 3 different numbers

I was able to do the first part however my second part of part is not working.

Here is the part not working:

```
int getDiff(int CLP, int Num)
{

    int counter = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    for (int x = CLP, i = 0; x >= 1; x /= 10, i++) {
        PlateNumberArray[i] = x % 10;

        cout << endl
             << "Test===>" << PlateNumberArray[i] << endl;

    } // end of "x = CLP" for loop

    while (i < Num) {
        j = 0;
        while (j <= Num) {
            if (PlateNumberArray[i] == PlateNumberArray[j])
                NumberCounter[i]++;
            j++;
        } //end of while(j <= i)
        i++;
    } //end of while(i < Num)

    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        counter += NumberCounter[i];

    return counter;
}
```

if for example my input is 112233 the return value should be 3, however i am getting 12

if input is 1122 the return value should be 2, however i am getting 8

Here is the whole program i have written so far:

```
/*====================================================================================
Headers and namespace
======================================================================================*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*====================================================================================
Prototypes list
======================================================================================*/

int getNum(int); //This function checks how many digits there are in a plate number
int getDiff(int, int); //This function checks how many different numbers are there in the plate number

/*====================================================================================
Global variables list
======================================================================================*/

int PlateNumberArray[6];
int NumberCounter[6];

/*====================================================================================
main Function
======================================================================================*/
int main()
{

    //Declaring variables

    int CLP;

    //End of Vriables Declration

    cout << endl
         << "=============================" << endl;

    cout << "Enter your vehicle's plate number" << endl;

    do {
        cin >> CLP;

        if (CLP >= 1000000)
            cout << "Plate number can be no longer than 6 digits, please re-enter" << endl;
        else if (CLP < 100 && CLP >= 0)
            cout << "Plate number can not be less than 3 digits, please re-eneter" << endl;
        else if (CLP < 0)
            cout << "Plate number can not be a negative, please re-eneter" << endl;

    } while (CLP >= 1000000 || CLP < 100);

    int Num = getNum(CLP);
    cout << getDiff(CLP, Num);

    return 0;
}
/*====================================================================================
getNum Function
======================================================================================*/
int getNum(int CLP)
{

    //Declaring variables

    int Num;

    //End of Vriables Declration

    if (CLP > 99999)
        Num = 6;
    else if (CLP > 9999)
        Num = 5;
    else if (CLP > 999)
        Num = 4;
    else if (CLP > 99)
        Num = 3;

    return Num;
}
/*====================================================================================
getDiff Function
======================================================================================*/
int getDiff(int CLP, int Num)
{

    int counter = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    for (int x = CLP, i = 0; x >= 1; x /= 10, i++) {
        PlateNumberArray[i] = x % 10;

        cout << endl
             << "Test===>" << PlateNumberArray[i] << endl;

    } // end of "x = CLP" for loop

    while (i < Num) {
        j = 0;
        while (j <= Num) {
            if (PlateNumberArray[i] == PlateNumberArray[j])
                NumberCounter[i]++;
            j++;
        } //end of while(j <= i)
        i++;
    } //end of while(i < Num)

    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        counter += NumberCounter[i];

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You have some UB when j== 6 in `if (PlateNumberArray[i] == PlateNumberArray[j])` Valid indices are 0 .. 5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `j` each time you increment `i`.

Comment: I have tried that, still didn't work :(

Comment: Reset it to `i+1`, not 0.